# Case In-sensitive query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I try to make a registration form. When user post the fields, i check USER_NAME. If exist then no inster the row to MYSQL.

After post:

```
$check = "SELECT name FROM test WHERE name='".$_POST['user_name']."';  
 $result = mysql_query($check) or die (mysql_error()); 
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($resutl);
 if ($numrow != 0){ 
     echo "exist"; exit;           
 }else{ 
     insert.....
 }
```

In the database i have a row with user_name=Test

If the posted value is Test, then ok, but if i post "test" or "TeSt" or something else, then the row iserted.

How can make it case insensitive? I think i should use str to lowercase to the posted value, but in the query..how can i do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the collation of your field is a case-insensitive one (such as `utf8_general_ci` or `latin1`), you can use the `LIKE` operator to do a case-insensitive match.

```
"SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE '$username';"
```

Comment: i changed collation from UTF-8 to Latin2 and now works great. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try `SELECT name FROM test WHERE UPPER(name)='".strtoupper($_POST['user_name'])."'`

be aware that you should correctly escape posted username (see php [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function)

Comment: Beware of potential XSS threats this piece of code might cause. You definitely should filter your input.

Comment: Thats not work with latin chars. UPPER and STRTOUPPER give different output to latin chars.

Comment: I think this should if write a function to strupper with special chars (like latin)

Comment: There are alternative "strtoupper" in php doc (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) to handle latin chars (ex. uc_latin1 function)

Answer (score 1):

The case sensitivity also depends on the data type of the column.  You can probably fix the problem without the extra overhead of the string conversions (i.e. `UPPER()` and `strtoupper()`) by changing the column type to VARCHAR.

[From the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

> For nonbinary strings (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT), string searches use the collation of the comparison operands. For binary strings (BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB), comparisons use the numeric values of the bytes in the operands; this means that for alphabetic characters, comparisons will be case sensitive.
>
> A comparison between a nonbinary string and binary string is treated as a comparison of binary strings.
>
> Simple comparison operations (>=, >, =, <, <=, sorting, and grouping) are based on each character's “sort value.” Characters with the same sort value are treated as the same character. For example, if “e” and “é” have the same sort value in a given collation, they compare as equal.