# how to make SQL query case sensitive?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

this is my php code where i am trying to create login system which is working just fine but lets say if the user have password = 'abcd' in a database and if they input 'ABCD', they still can login which i don't want. I want my SQL query to be case sensitive.

```
class Login extends Connection {
    private $userName;
    Private $password;

    public function userLogin($userName, $password) {

        $this -> userName = $userName;
        $this -> password = $password;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = :userName AND user_password = :password";

        $stmt = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> execute(array(
            ':userName' => $this -> userName,
            ':password' => $this -> password
        ));

        if($stmt -> rowCount() == 1) {
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
            header("location:../index.php");
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['loginMessage'] = "signin unsucessful";
        }
    }
}
```

i also tried something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = :userName AND user_password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = :password";
```

and i tried

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = :userName AND BINARY user_password = :password";
```

but none of them working.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/

Comment: You're going to have problems if and when you decide to switch over to using a safe hashing function such as `password_hash()`, did you know that? I highly suggest against what you're wanting to do. If you continue with this, it will just be a matter of time before your site/db get hacked; it's your site and your users' sensitive information after all.

Comment: @Fred i know about all these stuff, i presented my php code this way because i want my question to look as simple as possible and i want to focus on my real problem that is how to make sql query case sensitive? avobe php code is just an example.

Comment: See if anything in this Q&A helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694692/1415724

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs = :userName AND user_password COLLATE latin1_general_cs = :password`

Comment: i tested it and it works but the problem is after using this query, 
header("location:../index.php"); this line of code is not running.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. If I answered your question, please mark my answer to indicate that.

Try changing "../index.php" to "http://www.yahoo.com" and let us know if that worked. You could also try adding a call to exit() after the call to header().

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted if the OP acknowledged that it worked?

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem you definitely **don't** want to solve. Saving passwords in plain text is very, very bad idea. What to do? [Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) and [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) the passwords.

Why?
[Never store plain passwords!](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html)

How?
[Hashing and salting in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Do what the random person on the internet tells you to. _Seriously_, hashing passwords is **super** important. Not to mention essential

Comment: @Art this is not a answer i am looking for. My question is about how to make SQL query case sensitive, not how to do hashing passwords?

Comment: @NawarajBista I know. But no sane person on SO will explain you how to store plain passwords. Simply because it's a major security risk.

Comment: @NawarajBista If that's the case then you should use a different example of why you needed case insensitivity. Whilst I agree the question is not answered. It has addressed a key concern of your script that needs to be changed.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, should be a comment

Answer (score 1):

Agree about salting passwords, but this should work for case sensitive comparisons in MySQL.

```
select case when cast('test' as binary) = cast('TEST' as binary) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Regardless of the unusual motivation for the question, this should be accepted answer because it actually solved problems for people not comparing passwords. Like me.

Answer (score 0):

please don't store plain passwords.

but, answering your question, probably the database is using a collation that is case insensitive.

you would have to set the collation on database or set the collation to be used in the query.